# How insert user input in Angular HTTP post method header?

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, http-post

I am trying to take the user's input and put it into the header of a post method I am calling. I know some sort of binding is required but I am not sure how to apply it here. What I have so far is a variable called postData which I hardcoded in the parameter but I want the parameter to be by user input.

Here is the relevant part of my component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {

  value = '';
  update(value: string) { this.value = value; }
 

  postData ={ 
    name: "apple"
  } ; 

  getResults(postData){
    

    this.http.post<any>('APIUrlhere/issuerRestService/findIssuersBySearchCriteria', postData ).subscribe(data => {
    this.searchResult = data; 
    console.log(this.searchResult)
})

  }



}
```

Here is my HTML where I am getting the user input which I call "value".

```
<div>
        <label> Enter Company Name </label>
        <input #box
        (keyup.enter)="update(box.value)"
        (blur)="update(box.value)">
            
            <button (click)="getResults(postData)">Search</button>
           
        </div>
```

Any direction would be great, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. JSON.stringify-

```
const data = JSON.stringify(postData);
return this.http.post('APIUrlhere/issuerRestService/findIssuersBySearchCriteria',
data, requestOptions);
```

which sends the data in the request body.

2. Headers with http client

```
    const myheader = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    let body = new HttpParams();
    body = body.set('postData', postData);
    this.http.post('APIUrlhere/issuerRestService/findIssuersBySearchCriteria', body, {
        headers: myheader});
```

3. Request param

```
    var body = 'postdata=' + postData;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http
      .post('APIUrlhere/issuerRestService/findIssuersBySearchCriteria',
        body, {
        headers: headers
      });
```

I suggest you read up on http requests in Angular.

[Here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples) is a great link to explain angular http post.

In the html file, you can change it to send the value of the input directly into the function, instead of keeping it in the code (unless it is needed for future reference...)

```
<div>
    <label> Enter Company Name </label>
    <input #box
    (keyup.enter)="update(box.value)"
    (blur)="update(box.value)">
        
        <button (click)="getResults(box.value)">Search</button>
       
    </div>
```

**Pure HTML, JS example:**

```js
var value = '';
  function update(value) { this.value = value; }
 

  var postData = { 
    name: "apple"
  }; 

  function getResults(postData){
alert(postData);

  }
```

```html
<div>
        <label> Enter Company Name </label>
        <input #box id="box"
        (keyup.enter)="update(box.value)"
        (blur)="update(box.value)">
            <button onclick="getResults(box.value)">Search</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: I am still not understanding where I can add in the user input to the header? the user input being the var called "value".

Comment: @GurmesaShakme you sent it to the function as 'postData'. These snippets are relying on that value sent to the function.

Comment: I want to insert the user inputted value where "apple" is postData.                 
          postData ={ 
    name: **user data here***
  } ;

Comment: @GurmesaShakme why don't you just send box.value to the function? as in (click)="getResults(box.value)"